# How can I change the Google Chrome webapp icon?

Tags: icons, google-chrome, webapps

So I've got the AskUbuntu chatroom (I'm just using this as an example, I've got other webapps that I've got the same issue with) saved as a "Application Shortcut" in Chromium, and the icon is really (And I mean really) low resolution. Example:

[image]

The top one is the default icon that's used for the Application Shortcut, the bottom is the AskUbuntu lens - so my question is, how can I use the icon that's used for the AskUbuntu lens.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With daily chromium builds and [recent BAMF](http://castrojo.tumblr.com/post/4235430218/web-app-matching-with-chromium-and-unity) you can (if you look closer to that [screenshot](http://go.3v1n0.net/dOnhlF), you can see an example with my site and high-res icon). But in the current state of chromium you need to do some hacking to make it support this easily:

- Make chromium generate a .desktop file for the application Menu too (if you don't want you to create one by scratch).
- Get your chromium app window WM_CLASS with `xprop | grep WM_CLASS | awk '{print $4}'` (if it's just "Chromium Browser" or something similar you need to update chromium).
- Edit that .desktop file (located into `~/.local/share/applications`) with gedit or any other text editor; the file should contain:

  ```
  StartupWMClass=$APP_WM_CLASS_Found_on_step_2
  Icon=~/your/icon/file/name/or/path
  ```

  i.e. (for an app pointing to http://mail.google.com with `google_mail.png` in `~/.local/share/icons`):

  ```
  StartupWMClass=mail.google.com
  Icon=google_mail.png
  ```
- Restart bamfdaemon or unity at all; now when you'll run an application with that WM_CLASS the settings defined in the desktop file you've just edited will be used; icon included ;)

Comment: Been trying with no luck. :l Using Chromium nightly, and also using a Up-to-date Unity install. :(

Comment: @James Gifford: the currently bamfdemon package available in natty has not updated yet. You need to compile it [from bzr](https://code.launchpad.net/~unity-team/bamf/trunk) to get this working.

Comment: @James, now bamfdaemon package in natty should be updated. Give it a try again! ;)

Comment: the xprop trick doesn't work. It just returns "google-chrome" . Update of course doesn't fix it.

Comment: The method described above is complex and outdated. Consider installing menulibre instead, as indicated below by @Akashar Patel. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the easiest and fastest way.

Install Menu Editor:

```
sudo apt install menulibre
```

Open Menu Editor, Select App, Click on icon to select a new icon:

[image]

Comment: this was the easier way for me for sure. Thanks,

Comment: Awesome tool, should come standard.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for me was to [install Alacarte](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/alacarte) (free from the Software Center) and edit the icon from there. It looks like an application to edit regular GNOME 2/GNOME Classic icons, but it works for Unity Launcher icons as well. The Chrome webapps are under "Chrome Applications", at least in my machine.