# KDE Plasma 5.4.2 task switcher displays some icons pixelated

Tags: kubuntu, icons, kde, plasma

## The problem

I installed *Kubuntu 15.10* with *KDE Plasma 5.4.2* on my Dell. However, when I use the task switcher (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>), which is configured to list large image models of the running applications, some of the icons are displayed with lower resolution compared to others. For example, in my case, this problem can be seen with the *Google Chrome*, *Skype*, *Mozilla Firefox* icons. (See the pictures below)

---

## What I have tried

Here is a list of the things I tried but none of them helped resolving the problem:

- I downloaded a custom icon with higher resolution and replaced all Google Chrome icons in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/SizexSize`. **This changed the application icon upon launching and in the status bar but not in the task switcher.**
- Following [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33323/how-can-i-change-the-google-chrome-webapp-icon) I added the correct `WM_CLASS` attribute (which is `google-chrome`) to the `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` file.

---

## Pictures

*The current situation where the google chrome has a low resolution icon*
[image]

*How the task switcher should look like with the new google chrome icon:*
[image]

Comment: Here is some deeper information on this: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=351055 Long story short: It is stated that the responsive devs of each app would have to include higher resolution icons for their windows. (Last comment as of Nov. 2016)

Comment: You've not actually asked a question ... it looks like "Can I increase the resolution of the app icon in the task-switcher?" but it might be worth editing to spell it out. Did you try a different icon set?