# How do I change the icon of an internet shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, boinc

How do I change the icon of an internet shortcut (to a webpage, not an app), in this case one that will open in Chrome? This change is to be for a specific shortcut, not a global change. If it makes a difference, the URLis http://client.foldingathome.org/ Thank you.

Comment: Just edit the launcher (same as shortcut, I guess) and select another icon. It is a text file, so use a text editor.

Comment: First thing I tried was to edit the shortcut's properties. No option to change the icon. Note, this is the Pop OS version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Popos is not Ubuntu, and it isn't supported here. Perhaps they use different tech for "shortcuts", who knows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a shortcut for URL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359492/create-a-shortcut-for-url)

Comment: Refer this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1181688/534414

Answer (score 1):

Taking a hint from Jamie, I abandoned editing the original file, asked Google, and found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359492/create-a-shortcut-for-url).

The new file contains the following text only* and works great.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=F@H WebCtrl
Type=Link
URL=http://client.foldingathome.org/
Icon=/home/steve/Downloads/cropped-folding-at-home-logo-1-300x300.png
```

*provided you edit the .desktop file and DO NOT select the icon to `Open with Other Application`.

Answer (score 0):

Manually edit the desktop launcher file using a text editor such as `nano` or `gedit`:

```
gedit FoldingClient.desktop
```

This should load a file starting with `[Desktop Entry]`.

Find the line starting with `Icon`, or add it if is doesn't exist. You can specify a path to your desired icon:

```
Icon=/home/user/Pictures/FoldingIcon.png
```

Comment: Thanks, jamieweb. How do I deal with the error, "Could not save the file "http://client.foldingathome.org/" - Cannot handle "http:" locations in write mode. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again"? P.S. I cannot access the file via Terminal - all I get is a blank file. I *can* access it by right-click and open with Text editor, but obviously cannot do so as sudo.

Comment: Actually, the file starts out (with new icon identified) with `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Local Folding@home Web Control</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/home/steve/Downloads/cropped-folding-at-home-logo-1-300x300.png"/>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://client.foldingathome.org/"/>`